# Why might PostgreSQL CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY never make progress?

Tags: postgresql

What are reasons CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY in PostgreSQL "hangs", i.e. that it never seems to finish?  By "never" I mean in 24 hours it has not completed.  Here are the details.

I've this table:

```
               Table "public.user_verifying_attempts"
     Column      |            Type             |     Modifiers      
-----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------
 user_id         | integer                     | not null
 type            | userverificationtype        | not null
 value           | text                        | not null
 code            | character(10)               | not null
 attempts        | integer                     | default 0
 emails_sent     | integer                     | not null default 0
 last_email_sent | timestamp without time zone |
```

It has ~7.5M rows in it.  I'm trying to create an index by submitting this statement to the console (psql):

```
create index concurrently user_verifying_attempts_code_value_idx on user_verifying_attempts (code)';
```

I see no evidence of this index creation waiting on 'Idle in Transaction' processes, and I see no evidence of anything related in `pg_stat_activity`.

Moreover, I actually created this index in just this way earlier in the week on a copy of our production database, and it finished in ~90s.  That's consistent with another index I created last week on a different but slightly larger table, both on production and on the copy.  What that information gives me is a rough order-of-magnitude estimate for how long I should wait.  Minutes, definitely.  Hours, maybe.  But, days?  Something's gotta be wrong.

Finally, I have set `maintenance_work_mem` up from the default 16MB to 1GB (the host has ~160GB of memory).

Comment: You should still see the `create index` query in `pg_stat_activity` `index concurrently` takes a "back seat" to other queries FWIW.  Maybe some other connection has a lock on the table so it can't be applied or some odd?

Comment: I believe you.  And yet, I see nothing in `pg_stat_activity` whose `query` field has `create index...` and I also see nothing in `pg_locks` locking the `user_verifying_attempts` table.

Comment: Ugh.  I recognize that this is difficult to diagnose with so little info.  I appreciate the attempts.  Anyway, I just killled my `psql` session, created a new one, and re-ran the attempt.  It finished in 70s.  I'm baffled, but happy to have my index.  I may delete this question, as it's not very useful.

Comment: Feels as if maybe the network connection was lost or something weird. Oh well.

Comment: I know this is an old question but if you don't see anything in `pg_stat_activity` while `psql` is running then it means that postgresql killed your session however your `psql` did not react to that. There can be several reasons: 1. bug in `psql` (possible yet unlikely), 2. problem with network, very likely, especially if you connect to the db via incorrectly configured proxy. But even without proxy still likely. Anyway always check `pg_stat_activity`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lock on this table `user_verifying_attempts` that is not released because of some other transaction. Scan `pg_locks` table to see if there's anything interesting going on there

Comment: There  are no locks evident in `pg_locks` on the table `user_verifying_attempts`.